# How to constraint object rotation to certain degree?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have steering wheel that is controlled by physical daydream controller(it works similar to wii controller). I use this code to do it:

```
void Update() {
    transform.localRotation = GvrController.Orientation;
    transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, -transform.localRotation.y, transform.localRotation.w);
}
```

I need to mess with axis, beacause default position of the controller isn't good for a steering wheel.

But in 3-axis angle between maximum rotation to the left and to the right is 180 degrees. In this range everything is fine, but if I rotate a little bit more this values change to negative and everything is messed up. What can i do to allow the player to rotate only in this range(0 - 180 on z axis of 3-axis rotation)?

EDIT: The main problem is that the values of rotation after crossing 0 or 180 change to negative values, which are the same for both, but in different order. After crossing 0 it s form -1 to -180 and and for 180 its -180 to -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, we need a value that we can actually clamp. We'll get that from the [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html).z field (as a typical onscreen wheel rotates about z - you might need to change that to some other field depending on the controller):

```
void Update() {

    // Get the angle:
    float angle = GvrController.Orientation.eulerAngles.z;

    // The magic - clamp it:
    if(angle < -180f){
        angle = -180f;
    }
    else if(angle > 180f){
        angle = 180f;
    }

    // Apply it as a new rotation:
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f,0f,angle);
}
```

Comment: Quaternion.AngleAxis takes float and Vector3 as an arguments, should I use different function?

Comment: @faken Edited: try `Quaternion.Euler` instead (I must admit - I don't use the euler approach much myself, but it makes it very easy to follow)

Comment: When i use it its even more messed up, works wrong even in 'range'. I think that's because of converting Vector3 to quaternion.

Comment: @faken You'll possibly need to change the axis around (as that'll depend on the controller). I.e. maybe use `eulerAngles.y` instead. In your question you're directly using the 'y' component of a quaternion, which will, in short, give you unexpected results.

Comment: @faken Right ok I see what you're saying now - Quaternions are wonderful when used well. A controller has no idea that you're holding it upside down - all it knows is its absolute orientation. So what you're actually looking for is how to avoid the very sudden 'jolt' caused when someone rotates the controller upside down and then 'keeps going'?

Comment: I figured it out and added an answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (transform.eulerAngles.z > 180)
     transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.y, 180);
else if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 0)
     transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
```

Comment: This messes everything up because of what i wrote in EDIT :/

Comment: I have a small question about the code. Do you create the new rotation for the z-axis by using the euerAngles.y, because the Z-Rotation rotates around that axis? Or could explain a bit why you use the Y-Values, and not X and Y for example or just the Z-Values?

Comment: and yeah, this code does not work properly. it messes the rotation up

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wonders I found a solution, based on a script from Luke's answer. I realized that the values that change to negative are fine, only thing wrong with them is that they are negative. So this is the working script:

```
transform.localRotation = GvrController.Orientation;

float angle = -transform.localRotation.y;

if (angle < 0.0f) {
    angle = Mathf.Abs(angle);
}

transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, angle, transform.localRotation.w);
```

Comment: FWIW you're still using the raw components of a quaternion, which will give unexpected results in some cases. A quaternion represents an angle and some arbitrary axis (e.g. There's two solutions which will give the same visible rotation, but that y component is completely different - so it'd appear broken in your usage).

Comment: I don't know, probably you are right, but it works great so it seems that I'm just lucky then.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
If (transform.rotation > 180)
     transforn.rotation = 180;
```

Comment: There's about 3 issues with this. firstly we are using `localRotation`, not `rotation`, secondly, you are checking if the rotation is 180 degrees. **what?**, you have to check an axis. Thirdly, it is going into negative numbers, so this check would do nothing to fix the issue even if it was written correctly, as it should instead be `if(transform.localRotation.z < 0)`

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].